# How can my BottomNavigationBar float above hero widgets during page transitions?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want my NavigationBar to float above my Images during page transitions. These images are marked as hero widgets so they expand and get placed at the top of the "details" page, but during the page transition the bottom ones clip with the NavBar, since the NavBar is not persistent in my case and hero widgets are supposed to float above the previous' page widgets.

I know an easy fix would be to also include a NavBar on the next page and mark both as Hero widgets aswell, but I don't want/need the Bar on the details page.

Is there another way to fix that?

- [Initial state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0HDe.jpg)
- [User pressed bottom image (partly behind the NavBar), it clips through the navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfUq3.jpg)
- [The image further expands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2N38.jpg)